# nokia music app not inside windows phone 8 emulator

Tags: windows-phone-8-emulator

I have visual studio 2012 express for windows phone . And i need to implement

nokia music c# api in my app. But when i use the api inside the app I am unable to

see how it's working, since the emulator does not have the nokia music app inside it, which

is must required to see how the app is working.

So now I am stuck and unable to find the solution to it.

Please help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You will need a physical device to test Nokia Music API. Since emulator is not a physical device, you will not be able to install Nokia Music App in it.